# Iron.seal does not work when user log in

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, iron

`Iron.seal` does not work on updating npm module Iron ,that's why I faced this issue on log in the user

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: [3, 4, 5],
    d: {
        e: 'f'
    }
};

var password = 'some_not_random_password_that_is_at_least_32_characters';

Iron.seal(obj, password, Iron.defaults, function (err, sealed) {`

    console.log(sealed);
});
```

Can anyone guide me why I faced this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the similar issue when I updated the `iron` npm package.

The docs on [github](https://github.com/hueniverse/iron) are updated. instead of callback they are now using async await.

What you can do is:

```
try {
 const sealed = await Iron.seal(obj, password, Iron.defaults);
 console.log(sealed);
  } 
catch (err) {
 console.log(err.message);
}
```